# When to use let vs. if-let in Clojure

Tags: clojure

When does using `if-let` rather than `let` make code look better and does it have any performance impact?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I guess [if-let](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/if-let) should be used when you'd like to reference an `if` condition's value in the "`then`" part of the code:

i.e. instead of

```
(let [result :foo]
  (if result
    (do-something-with result)
    (do-something-else)))
```

you write:

```
(if-let [result :foo]
  (do-something-with result)
  (do-something-else))
```

which is a little neater, and saves you indenting a further level. As far as efficiency goes, you can see that the macro expansion doesn't add much overhead:

```
(clojure.core/let [temp__4804__auto__ :foo]
  (if temp__4804__auto__
    (clojure.core/let [result temp__4804__auto__]
      (do-something-with result))
    (do-something-else)))
```

This also illustrates that the binding can't be referred to in the "`else`" part of the code.

Comment: Also, it is not possible to have more than 2 forms in the binding vector of if-let. Eg: (if-let [a 20 b nil] (println a)) - does not work!

Comment: @SusheelJavadi you can create your own if-let* block, similar to https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/if-let#example-5b8deb7ce4b00ac801ed9e81

Answer (score 35):

A good use case for `if-let` is to remove the need to use anaphora.  For example, the Arc programming language provides a macro called `aif` that allows you to bind a special variable named `it` within the body of an `if` form when a given expression evaluates to logical true.  We can create the same thing in Clojure:

```
(defmacro aif [expr & body]
  `(let [~'it ~expr] (if ~'it (do ~@body))))

(aif 42 (println it))
; 42
```

This is fine and good, except that anaphora do not nest, but `if-let` does:

```
(aif 42 (aif 38 [it it]))
;=> [38 38]

(aif 42 [it (aif 38 it)])
;=> [42 38]

(if-let [x 42] (if-let [y 38] [x y]))
;=> [42 38]
```